# Objective C: use tag for textfield

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string, tags, uitextfield

I have this code

```
- (IBAction) addNumberField {


if ([firstField.text  intValue] == 3) 
{   
    firstField.text = @"0"; 
}
else
{
    int num = [firstField.text intValue];
    num = num + 1;
    firstField.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:num] stringValue];
}
}
```

you can see that with this IBAction I increase textfield value with a button and the range is 0-3. But I want use this IBAction also for an other textfield not only firstField, but also for secondField (second textField). I think that I should use tag, but I don't know the way. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you need to apply the same code to different objects or values, you define a method like this:

```
- (void)updateNumberField:(UITextField *)textField {
    int num = [textField.text intValue];
    num = (num + 1) % 4;  // this will wrap num to the range [0, 3]
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", num];
}

- (IBAction)addNumberField {
    [self updateNumberField:firstField];
    [self updateNumberField:secondField];
    // you can do the same for whatever field you like
}
```

It is, of course, possible to use tags by assigning `num` to `textField.tag` in `updateNumberField:` method. It will save you a conversion from `NSString` to `int`.

If you need to attach any additional values to your text fields, consider making a subclass and add all the required functionality to it.

Comment: your code update textfield at the same time, I have two different button, one for the first textfield and a second button for the second textfiled.

Comment: @blackguardian You can easily call `[self updateNumberField:firstField]` in the action for the first button and `[self updateNumberField:secondField]` in the action for the second button.

Answer (score 0):

assign tag to each text field in IB if you are using IB and in code call setTag to each textfield.

Comment: why are you calling intValue here?

Comment: if you want to assign tag use [textfield setTag:1]; and if you want to compare a already assign tag value to an integer use [textfield tag] == 1

Answer (score 0):

In `.h` file we declare the code for textfield, i.e:

```
uitextfield *tf;
```

In `.m` file we implement that one.

In viewdidload:

```
{
    tf=[uitextfield alloc]initwithframe:(cgrectmake(x axis,y axis, width, height))];
    [self.view addsubview:tf];
}
```